# NOdeJs Rest API response encoded with private key

Tags: node.js, api, rest, private-key, pgp

I have been supplied with a public and private key to call a restAPI in nodejs.
Both keys are in clear ASCII format.

I use the following code to encript my message:

```
(async () => {
    // put keys in backtick (``) to avoid errors caused by spaces or tabs

    // ENCRYPT

    const publicKeyArmored = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyFile, {
      encoding: 'utf8',
      flag: 'r'
    });
    
    const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyArmored });

    const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
        message: await openpgp.createMessage({ text: 'Hello, World!' })
    ,   encryptionKeys: publicKey
    // ,        signingKeys: privateKey // optional
    });
    
    console.log("Encrypted:", encrypted); // '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ... END PGP MESSAGE-----'
}
```

However when I try to decrypt the response, all the code examples I have found seem to require a passphrase to use the private key supplied, but this is not encoded in any way, it's again plain ascii, begining with :

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)

lQO+BGHApmABCAC70QG0T3bh1MVRGKmY9cOM2NFEie2KXCLGXUPa+2B5JOnDypGX
msoLau8FtKIqvAVAYSsONlE4P4RcltyrOTHLMvWhu73ZTJIBu6GGkgM6bKOtu2Rp
/VbPylPIXrkA3A4s0089VGgmFqJul04lit2svLwxD31ZEIY3Ke3kd0dV0nM4npRO
EZUPR5Qr6KCwBsL+ZHbDuG2YrC7oKcnJTXcdszrF7+FLAwI8viZhJOXyagJRioXd
/H/IpauXyvejN22/eRjch9IRMSz+qh0avj9tcuuJ1k4sBQQukeoIoPwFe9Rb9TY2 .....
```

the following code suggests I need a passphrase, but this key does not appear to require one:

```
async function decrypt() {
  const privateKey = (await openpgp.key.readArmored([privateKeyArmored])).keys[0];
  await privateKey.decrypt(passphrase);

  const encryptedData = fs.readFileSync("encrypted-secrets.txt");
  const decrypted = await openpgp.decrypt({
    message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encryptedData),
    privateKeys: [privateKey],
  });

  console.log(decrypted.data);
}
```

SO how do I use it without a passphrase?

Thank you in advance for your xmas spirit and any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your private key is `ASCII armored`, so it is possible to transfer it in text representation. After calling `gpg --dearmor` on it you'll get the binary data. Also private key may be stored using the password encryption, or not encrypted at all (in the second case you will not need to call `privateKey.decrypt()`). To check this you may use the command `gpg --list-packets keyfile.asc`.